# Loop through multiple JSON array

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

Here is a snippet of my JSON, it is very long and after the "menu" section it goes back to "Location" and starts over witha  new place.  I have no idea why but where I loop through and print it to my logcat it will stop at a random place in the "Menu" section and throw an error.  I don't understand how to access the whole menu section.

```
{
"locations": [{
    "Location": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Scott Express Cafe",
        "building": "PKI",
        "monday_hours": "8am-2:30pm",
        "tuesday_hours": "8am-2:30pm",
        "wednesday_hours": "8am-2:30pm",
        "thursday_hours": "8am-2:30pm",
        "friday_hours": "8am-2:30pm",
        "saturday_hours": "Closed",
        "sunday_hours": "Closed"
    },
    "Section": [{
        "id": "3",
        "location_id": "1",
        "name": "Snacks",
        "Location": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Scott Express Cafe",
            "building": "PKI",
            "monday_hours": "8am-2:30pm",
            "tuesday_hours": "8am-2:30pm",
            "wednesday_hours": "8am-2:30pm",
            "thursday_hours": "8am-2:30pm",
            "friday_hours": "8am-2:30pm",
            "saturday_hours": "Closed",
            "sunday_hours": "Closed"
        },
        "Menu": [{
            "id": "278",
            "location_id": "1",
            "item_name": "Pop-tarts",
            "price_small": "$1.00",
            "price_medium": "",
            "price_large": "",
            "special": false,
            "special_start": "",
            "special_end": "",
            "details": "",
            "section_id": "3"
        }, {
            "id": "279",
            "location_id": "1",
            "item_name": "Cereal Bar",
            "price_small": "$1.00",
            "price_medium": "",
            "price_large": "",
            "special": false,
            "special_start": "",
            "special_end": "",
            "details": "",
            "section_id": "3"
        },
```

**Here is the error:**

```
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): },
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): {
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "price_medium": "",
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "id": "295",
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "details": "",
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "price_large": "",
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "item_name": "Wheat Thins Toasted Chips",
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "special_end": "",
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "special_start": "",
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "section_id": "3",
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "special": false,
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "price_small": "$0.85",
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "location_id": "1"
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): },
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): {
07-02 20:08:19.878: D/TAG_LOCATIONS(4597): "pric
07-02 20:08:19.888: W/System.err(4597): org.json.JSONException: No value for id
07-02 20:08:19.908: W/System.err(4597):     at o   rg.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)        
07-02 20:08:19.908: W/System.err(4597):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
07-02 20:08:19.908: W/System.err(4597):     at com.example.androidtablayout.FoodMenuList.onCreate(FoodMenuList.java:87)
07-02 20:08:19.908: W/System.err(4597):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-02 20:08:19.918: W/System.err(4597):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-02 20:08:19.918: W/System.err(4597):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-02 20:08:19.918: W/System.err(4597):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-02 20:08:19.918: W/System.err(4597):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-02 20:08:19.918: W/System.err(4597):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-02 20:08:19.928: W/System.err(4597):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-02 20:08:19.939: W/System.err(4597):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-02 20:08:19.939: W/System.err(4597):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-02 20:08:19.948: W/System.err(4597):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 20:08:19.948: W/System.err(4597):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-02 20:08:19.958: W/System.err(4597):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-02 20:08:19.958: W/System.err(4597):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-02 20:08:19.958: W/System.err(4597):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**my Class:**

```
public class FoodMenuList extends Activity {

// url to make request for menus
private static String url =               "http://mavmate.atticdev.ist.unomaha.edu/api/v1/services/getMenus";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_LOCATIONS = "locations"; 
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "Location";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_BUILDING = "building";


// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray locations = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.foodmenulist_layout);   

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String locationIDThing = extras.getString("locationID");

 // Hashmap for textView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

try {
    // Getting Array of locations
    locations = json.getJSONArray(TAG_LOCATIONS);

    // looping through All locations
    for(int i = 0; i < locations.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = locations.getJSONObject(i);

      Log.d("TAG_LOCATIONS", locations.toString(i));

        // Storing each json item in variable
        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        String Location = c.getString(TAG_BUILDING);
        String building = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);


        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
        map.put(TAG_LOCATION, Location);
        map.put(TAG_BUILDING, building);
        //map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItemList.add(map);
    }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually parsing the JSON to get the data consider using the [GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to deserialize Java objects from JSON. For example, the following will convert a json string to a Person object.

```
Person p = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Person.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for "id" at wrong place in JSON
"id" is present inside either "Location" or elements of "Section"

But not directly in an element of "locations", which is where code is looking.

Edit:

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
for (JSONObject jsonObj : json.getJSONArray("locations"))
  for(JSONObject jsonObj2 : jsonObj.getJSONArray("Section"))
     for(JSONObject jsonObj3 : jsonObj2.getJSONArray("Menu"))
       System.out.println(jsonObj3.get("id");
```

Consider using "optXXX" functions instead of "getXXX" e.g. optString("id)

Comment: Could you please help me with how to loop through the "menu" section?

Comment: Thank you so much i'm going to test it :)

Comment: Just so you know you can't iterate through JSON